# Is it possible to lock guest VMs (or processes) to sticks of physical RAM to prevent row hammer attacks?

Tags: linux, malware, virtualization, hardening

I was wondering if it is possible through some means to isolate processes (or preferably guest VMs) to physical sticks of RAM. This would be to prevent row hammer like attacks from using physical layer vulnerabilities for breaking out of isolation across security domains (with each security domain being isolated to physical sticks of RAM). I imagined it as similar to how IOMMU can lock a graphics card or similar to a single virtual machine, but I'd like to be able to do this with RAM that the actual guest runs on and utilizes.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/674214/what-is-the-rowhammer-dram-bug-and-how-should-i-treat-it

Comment: In particular: `A solution is to buy hardware that supports pTRR or TRR.`

Comment: I was perhaps too general in my scenario, I'd like to be able to isolate sticks of RAM and pass them through to guest VMs to prevent any physical layer attacks that require shared physical RAM. Row Hammer is only one specific example, and indeed we know it is preventable with RAM that is protected from it. However, this technique has the potential to protect from the entire class of attacks that relies on sharing physical RAM between security domains, if it is possible to implement it, I'm not sure if it is possible to do.

Comment: What's wrong with dedicated airgapped servers instead of fickle VMs?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with physical isolation but that is no reason to not increase the security of virtualization or mandatory access control based isolation mechanisms. Indeed, this would in a sense bring virtualization based isolation closer to physical isolation by allowing for actual physical isolation of security domains to RAM, this brings it closer enough to full physical isolation to provide the protections of full physical isolation from row hammer type attacks (of course assuming it is possible, that's what I'm wondering. I know it is for everything from a mouse to CPU core, but RAM?).

Comment: Although the answers to your question could be used to increase security, the question itself is a virtualization architecture question and not an InfoSec question.

Comment: It isn't specific to virtualization, if you can isolate processes to sticks of RAM with mandatory access controls it would be an acceptable way of implementing it as well. I guess the question is, how can I isolate processes to dedicated physical sticks of memory that no other processes use, via any means. I would personally think about it in terms of virtualization or mandatory access controls, but however you can implement it with code / configurations (not physical isolation) is an acceptable answer.

Comment: @DeerHunter Actually, pTRR and TRR are not perfect. Even TRR does not guarantee that a particularly aggressive rowhammer attack will not succeed. Not to mention, while LPDDR4 requires TRR, DDR4 itself merely supports it, and it's generally impossible to tell if a given memory module actually supports and uses it.